# phpqrcode + save cached file to Amazon instead of folder on server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, save, qr-code

What I do now is creating a QR code image (PNG) and save a copy of it in a folder on the root of my server. Now I would like to save this image not on my server but on my amazon bucket.

I know how I can save a file on amazon but I can't figure out how to make this work together.
This is my original code for saving it in a root folder on my server:

```
$fileName = $quiz_url . '.png';

$pngAbsoluteFilePath = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/qrcodecaches/' . $fileName; 
$urlRelativeFilePath = '/qrcodecaches/' . $fileName;

// generating
if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    QRcode::png('http://mysitelink.com/s/'.$quiz_url, $pngAbsoluteFilePath, 'L', 4, 2);
}
```

And this is how I save a file on Amazon:

```
$bucket = 'mybucket';
$map = 'qrcodecaches';

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'mykey',
    'secret' => 'mysecret',
));


$fileName = $quiz_url . '.png';
$keyname = $map . '/' . $fileName;

try {
    $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'Body'   => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ));
   } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

But what do I need to save in the 'Body' tag? Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: The best tutorial which I got on youtube to use Amazon S3 to upload images and files. Here you will learn how you can use it in your script and you can upload it to Amazon CDN. This is link of [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75Z5ba03bZA) video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the image file passing a temporary file name like this:

```
$pngAbsoluteFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'qr_code_');
if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    QRcode::png('http://mysitelink.com/s/'.$quiz_url, $pngAbsoluteFilePath, 'L', 4, 2);
}
```

then all you need to do is to get that file contents and pass it in to the `Body` of the object in bucket:

```
try {
    $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'Body'   => file_get_contents($pngAbsoluteFilePath), // like this
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ));
   }
catch (S3Exception $e) {
   echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

After you're done - in case of successful upload - you can delete the temporary file. It is not necessary, however recommended because it will fill your `/tmp` with QR images until your server is restarted:

```
if ( empty($e) ) {
    unlink($pngAbsoluteFilePath);
}
```

This worked well for me.

Comment: Is your image generating properly? Can you see it after running the script in the `$pngAbsoluteFilePath` path? (make sure you don't unlik the file for tests)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3Client documentation suggests that you can poll to check that the upload was successful.

```
$client->waitUntilObjectExists(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $keyname
));
```

Alternatively if you're already writing the file to disk on your server you can supply S3Client with the path to that file and let it handle the filestream itself.

```
try {
    $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => $keyname,
        'SourceFile' => '/path/to/file',
        'ACL'        => 'public-read'
    ));
   } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

Source:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject